# Custom Fresnel with separate wavelength input

Tags: rendering, customization

How can I create a Fresnel effect taking in consideration the custom wavelength curve generated on refractiveindex for a more accurate fresnel effect in cycles.
[image]
. The simple IOR input isn't reflecting accurately enough what happens in reality.

Comment: I haven't looked quantitatively, but it seems the glass and transparent shaders are handling angle OK - you can get total internal reflection easily. Maybe use that code as a starting point. See for example: [http://imgur.com/qZEzv09](http://imgur.com/qZEzv09)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches, either adjust blender's code and build your own version. You may even be able to get your changes accepted into the official blender sources.

Or write [an osl script](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/osl.html) that calculates the way you want. As a starting point the official fresnel node is implemented as -

```
shader node_fresnel(
    float IOR = 1.45,
    normal Normal = N,
    output float Fac = 0.0)
{
    float f = max(IOR, 1e-5);
    float eta = backfacing() ? 1.0 / f : f;
    float cosi = dot(I, Normal);
    Fac = fresnel_dielectric_cos(cosi, eta);
}
```

And you can find [fresnel_dielectric_cos() here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/kernel/closure/bsdf_util.h$99)

Comment: I prefer the second approach but the problem is i can't code i don't know either python or OSL shader. I heard about OSL but my focused is on 3d modeling. I'll search about it and tell you if i can figure it out. Thanks a lot man it is n interesting starting point.